# How to get a list of all variable groups of Azure DevOps from custom build task?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-extensions

I'm creating my own extension for Azure DevOps pipeline and I want to list all variable Groups in dropdown box to be chosen by user. But I don't know how to do it in `task.json`.

I've tried different types of endpointId, such as `tfs:teamfoundation`, `tfs:feed`, but it doesn't work. Also I'm not sure about auth of this endpoint.

From postman I'm using basic auth to make a request, but in my extension I've defined scope: `vso.variablegroups_manage` and, probably, this should work.

```
"inputs": [
     {
         "name": "groupId",
         "type": "pickList",
         "label": "The Id of variable group",
         "defaultValue": "",
         "required": true,
         "helpMarkDown": "The id of variable group.",
         "properties": {
             "DisableManageLink": "True"
         }
     }
 ],
 "dataSourceBindings": [
     {
       "target": "groupId",
       "endpointId": "tfs:teamfoundation",
       "endpoint": "https://dev.azure.com/nameOfMyOrganization/nameOfMyProject/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups?api-version=5.1-preview.1",
       "resultSelector": "jsonpath:$.value[*]",
       "resultTemplate": "{ \"Value\" : \"{{{id}}}\", \"DisplayValue\" : \"{{{name}}}\" }"
     }
 ],
```

Please, help me with `dataSourceBinding` for my purpose.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: @Dejulia489, no I didn't.

Comment: Bummer. That would be very useful. Thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. I had to capture the network traffic from the ServiceNow *Approval and Checks* variable group selector.

The "manage gear/cog" still takes you to the wrong place but the drop down populates.

```
"dataSourceBindings": [
    {
      "target": "groupId",
      "endpointId": "tfs:teamfoundation",
      "endpointUrl": "{{endpoint.url}}/{{system.teamProject}}/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups?actionFilter=Use",
      "resultSelector": "jsonpath:$.value[*]",
      "resultTemplate": "{ \"Value\" : \"{{{name}}}\", \"DisplayValue\" : \"{{{name}}}\" }"
    },
 ],
```